# Python variable input into format string

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I currently have this code here:

```
test = 2.432
test_formatted = "{:.2f}".format(test)
print(test_formatted)
```

Output:

```
2.43
```

Is there a way to insert a variable for the number into the format string? Such as:

```
test = 2.432
te = 2
test_formatted = "{:." + str(te) + "f}".format(test)
print(test_formatted)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean f-strings? `f"{te:.2f}"`
I'm not sure what your expected result is, can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood for a sec. The f string trick appears to work for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
'{{:.{}f}}'.format(te)
# Result: '{:.2f}'
```

Or directly convert the number with an f-string (Python 3.6 and newer):

```
f'{test:.{te}f}'
# Result: '2.43'
```

Comment: It prints the result but in quotes:
'2.432'

Comment: Use it as the argument for `print()` or assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Add some parenthesis around the string you are creating and it works!

```
test = 2.432
te = 3
test_formatted = ("{:." + str(te) + "f}").format(test)
print(test_formatted)
```

Comment: It works just fine in regular Python, but not in discord.py:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string

Answer (score 1):

Using `f`-strings, you can do something like this:

```py
test = 2.432
te = 2
test_formatted = f"{test:.{te}f}"
print(test_formatted)
```

Output:

```py
2.43
```